# Angular method decorator error handling with subscriptions

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, subscription, typescript-decorator

Currently, I have an angular application with a method decorator to handle errors of all the methods in the component. It catches all the errors from methods, But it is unable to catch the error inside subscribe. Any suggestions to do this?

This is my current code.

This is the sampling method I want to catch the errors

```
  @logActionErrors()
  getEmailSettings() {
      this.sharedService.getSMTPConfigurations().subscribe(() => {
        throw('this is an error');
      }, (ex) =>{
        console.log(ex);
      })
  }
```

This is my Method Decorator

```
export function logActionErrors(): any {
    return function (target: Function, methodName: string, descriptor: any) {
        const method = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
            try {
                let result = method.apply(this, args);
                // Check if method is asynchronous
                if (result && result instanceof Promise) {
                    // Return promise
                    return result.catch((error: any) => {
                        handleError(error, methodName, args, target.constructor.name);
                    });
                }
                if(result && result instanceof Observable ){
                    console.log(methodName);
                    result.pipe(catchError((error: any) => {
                        console.log(error);
                        handleError(error, methodName, args, this.constructor.name);
                        return result
                    }))                
                }
                // Return actual result
                return result;
            } catch (error:any) {
                handleError(error, methodName, args, target.constructor.name);
            }
        }
        return descriptor;
    }
}
```

I want to catch this `throw('this is an error');` error on this sample. any suggestions to do this?

Comment: I would suggest you to use global error handler that handle everything, You dont have to attach anything anywhere https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler

Comment: @Indraraj26 I have a global error handler. But It is not showing the method name and component as it is in production mode.  It shows the minified results. In this way, I can track the method name and component name without any effort.